# Why does load-test fail with BSD and Perlversion 5.12.0 - 5.12.2?

Tags: perl, testing, module

What could be the reason that this test (t/00-load.t) fails with OS *BSD and Perl version from 5.12.0 to 5.12.2?

```
#!perl -T

use 5.010001;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More tests => 1;

BEGIN {
    use_ok( 'Term::Choose' ) || print "Bail out!\n";
}

diag( "Testing Term::Choose $Term::Choose::VERSION, Perl $], $^X" );
```

Error:

```
t/00-load.t               (Wstat: 139 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 139
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 1 tests but ran 0.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exit status 139 is 128 + 11, meaning signal 11, which is SIGSEGV, indicating a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).